# Xcode 6.0.1 NSManagedObject autogeneration doesn't work for existing classes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

It seems like autogeneration of NSManagedObject subclasses is broken in Xcode 6.0.1. I add a couple of properties to my entity, create new file, select NSManagedObject subclass, select my entity and click "Replace" when dialog appears, but new properties are not added. Creating classes for new entity works fine though. Did anyone face it?

Comment: yes, looks like it's happening for me too. hope there's a fix soon.

Comment: Consider using mogenerator, and raise bug reports with Apple

Comment: Still not fixed in the latest AppStore available release

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. You need to delete Class for your entity and create new NSManagedObject subclass. More detailed here: [Create NSManagedObject subclass not generating property after updating to Xcode 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853366/create-nsmanagedobject-subclass-not-generating-property-after-updating-to-xcode/28169667#28169667)