# iOS 8 - generating NSManagedObject from data model in Xcode not working

Tags: xcode, core-data, model, ios8, nsmanagedobject

Since I updated to Xcode 6.0 I cannot anymore create a new NSManagedObject from the Xcode data model. Before, I just selected new File and NSManagedObject, I selected my Entity and my Class I wanted to change and a new Class.h and m with new attributes were created and uploaded in my folder. But now, nothing happens after I decide to save and replace my old class. It comes up with the old class (and in the finder I indeed have the old one).

Does anyone know why or have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I was facing the exact same problem.

Solution :

1. Copy paste any code you added yourself in your generated NSManagedObject subclasses.
2. Delete all the generated files (not only the only you'd like to update.
3. Clean you project and folder (Shift + ⌘ + K then Shift + ⌘ + ⌥ + K)
4. Regenerate your NSManagedObjects subclasses by selecting them in the xcdatamodeld, then Editor, Create NSManagedObject Subclass

Comment: With the update the problem is gone... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. You need to delete Class files for your entity and create new NSManagedObject subclass. More detailed here: [Create NSManagedObject subclass not generating property after updating to Xcode 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853366/create-nsmanagedobject-subclass-not-generating-property-after-updating-to-xcode/28169667#28169667)