# iOS Swift CoreData Error on Insert: warning: Unable to load class for entity

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'm trying to insert elements into Core Data using Swift in Xcode 6.3.1 and I am getting an error.  I've adopted solutions from several Stackoverflow answers (listed at the bottom), but none are helping to resolve the issue.

I created another app to simplify the code and issues, hoping that it would provide greater benefit for others having this issue.

---

**The Error:**
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Scratch.Test' for entity 'Test'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

**The Code:** *(Updated: Pre-Fix)*

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let saveData = saveDataLabel.text
    println(saveData)

    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = "Test"
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(en, inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let test = Test(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    test.saveMe = saveData!
    var error: NSError?
    if !context.save(&error){
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    //        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Test")
    //        let fetchedEntities = appDel.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Test]
    //
    //        if(fetchedEntities.count == 0){
    //            NSLog("I'm empty")
    //        } else {
    //            NSLog("\(fetchedEntities[0].saveMe)")
    //        }

}
```

**The Data Model** *my apologies, I'm new here and not allowed to post an image*

App Name: Scratch

 - Scratch.xcdatamodeld

 - - Test (with *Class* = Scratch.Test)

 - - - saveMe (as String)

**Code in Test.swift**

```
        import Foundation
        import CoreData

        @objc(Test)
        class Test: NSManagedObject {

              @NSManaged var saveMe: String

        }
```

**Code in AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "self.com.AG.TaskIt" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
        }()
    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Scratch", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Scratch.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
        return coordinator
        }()
    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
        }()
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

I can't find anything that will get me past this error.  Here are some of the solutions I have found that did not work:

- [CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/swift-coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named)
- [CoreData: Unable to load class for entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236223/coredata-unable-to-load-class-for-entity?rq=1)
- [Unable to find specific subclass of NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unable-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject)

Comment: Show your fetch code.

Comment: Hello Mundi, I have updated the **The Code** section to show all of my code for the viewDidLoad() in the ViewController.  I am not currently using Fetch code.  Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: So this was one possible answer.
[image]

And[image]

Comment: Hello Prontto, thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, I retried **Editor->Create NSManaged Object Subclass**, and confirmed that I got the second screen (with the blue icon next to the selected Group, with the app name **Scratch** checked as the Target).  The error is still appearing.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that probably was in one of your answers, what you tried earlier.

Comment: Thank you, Prontto!  I actually did the exact opposite when I read that thread.  Removing the app name **Scratch.** from the Class in the Data Model Inspector fixed the issue.  Any chance you can take a screenshot of the **Data Model Inspector Window** in .xcdatamodeld, and add it to your answer so other users may find the answer easily?

Comment: If that helped, you can accept my answer. I'll add anyway screenshots.

Comment: My screenshots messed my text so I comment here another solution. Just remove `@objc(Test)` and define Entitys Class `Scratch.Test`

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the field 'Module' under 'Class' in the Data Model Inspector of the Utilities panel is set to **Current Product Module**.

In my case, the problem was caused by having *Global namespace* in that field (Xcode 9.4).

[image][image]