# FetchRequest - NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to do a `NSFetchRequest` to display my data into a `UICollectionView` :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
class GarageViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var voitures: [Voiture]  = [Voiture]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.reloadData()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Voiture")
    fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

    do {
        try voitures = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Voiture]
    }
    catch let fetchError as NSError {
        print("VoitureFetch error: \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if (voitures.count > 0) {
        for voiture in voitures as [Voiture] {

            print(voiture.nom!)

        }
    }
    else {
        print("Aucune voiture")
    }

}
```

When I run the code I get that error :

**`fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`**

Thank's for your help !

Comment: What is in the array returned by the fetch request. It isn't `Voiture` objects. It is probably `NSManagedObject` instances.

Comment: You can answer your own question (instead of posting Solution in your question), makes things easier for people stumbling on this in the future.

Comment: Ok thank you sbarow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

```
var voitures: [NSManagedObject]?  = [NSManagedObject]()


if (voitures!.count > 0) {

        let voiture: NSManagedObject = voitures![indexPath.row]

        print((voiture.valueForKey("nom") as? String))
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. 
The issue was due to not setting the class property for the entity in model file.

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks for pointing this out. Also needed this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named to get it working for me. I had to include @objc(ClassName)

Comment: In Addition to this, after setting the class name, set the module name to "Current Product Module".