# Unit Testing Core Data in XCode 7 Beta/Swift 2

Tags: unit-testing, core-data, swift2, xcode7

## In a Nutshell:

I'm trying to write a unit test for a Core Data model in XCode 7/Swift 2.  However, a simple test such as testing that the number of rows in the model is equal to what I know it to be fails (I know there to be one row, but the test sees none).  My best guess is that I'm getting a different (clean?) version of `managedObjectContext`, but I'm not sure how to get the same version as the app.  Besides the technique described below (following the linked instructions on Andrew Bancroft's site), I tried adding the application delegate to SOTestTests and getting the `managedObjectContext` as follows...

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

...but I then get an error that XCode `[c]ould not cast value of type 'SOTest.AppDelegate' (0x25bb8) to 'SOTestTests.AppDelegate' (0x2c7bb78).`

## Longform:

Here are the steps to set up the smallest reproducible example I could come up with:

1. Simple model: One `Entity` (`Person`) with one `Attribute` (`name`, type `String`).  `Person` is unique, `name` is non-optional.
2. Create a subclass (Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass...)
3. (Comment out `@objc(Person)` in `Person.swift` to avoid a build error.)
4. Add a single row to the model.  (Only run the code that gets an entity and saves it once--comment it out on subsequent runs to avoid getting a conflict error due to the `unique` property.)  Here's the `ViewController` that's doing this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Put a new person in the model.
        let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Person
        newPerson.name = "Harper Lee"

        // Save it
        do { try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch _ { NSLog("There was a problem saving to the database.") }

        // Sanity check
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

        do {
            let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Person]
            NSLog("Number of rows (App): \(fetchedResults!.count)") // 1
        } catch _ { NSLog("Well...that went badly.") }
    }
}
```

5. I then add the `Person` subclass files to `SOTestTests` (meta, I know) in Build Phases, setup the `managedObjectContext` according to the example on [Andrew Bancroft](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/13/unit-testing-model-layer-core-data-swift/)'s (excellent) site (with mods for Swift 2), and write the test checking if there is one row:

```
import XCTest
import CoreData

class SOTestTests: XCTestCase {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    func setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

        let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

        do {
            try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSInMemoryStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: nil, options: nil)
        } catch _ { NSLog("Problem adding the Persistent Store Coordinator") }

        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

        return managedObjectContext
    }

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        self.managedObjectContext = self.setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext()

    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // Check the number of rows in NUT_DATA
        do {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")
            let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Person]
            print("Number of rows (Test): \(fetchedResults!.count)") // Prints 0
            XCTAssert(1 == fetchedResults!.count, "Incorrect number of rows in `Person` entity.")
        } catch _ { NSLog("Error fetching the entity Person.") }
    }
}
```

6. Create a new scheme by selecting `SOTestTests`, and addthe `SOTest.app` executable to the run scheme.

When I run this, the `ViewController` class prints out that there is a single row, but the test prints out zero rows, and the test fails.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just import the actual project to get access to AppDelegate and other classes.

```
@testable import SOTest
```

No need to add everything to the test target.

Comment: If I import `SOTest` and `let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! SOTest.AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`, I get an error that there is `No type named AppDelegate in module SOTest`...

Comment: On a plain vanilla project, it works with your exact managed object context line without errors. Note that the newest Xcode automatically does the above import, like this: `@testable import SOTest`.

Comment: Adding `@testable import SOTest` to my `SOTestTests` class did the trick.  For some reason it couldn't cast the array as `[Person]` (I had to change it to `[NSManagedObject]`), but the test now passes!  Thanks!

Comment: For this last problem, consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614152/427083).

Comment: Nice!  Changing to `[SOTest.Person]` did it.  Would upvote twice if I could.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with @testable import!