# I'm having trouble fetching entities from core data based on relationships with predicates

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

**Quick background**: I have en ExamEntity, which is linked via a relationship to sections covered in the exam (SectionEntity), which is linked via a relationship to the subsections under each section (SubsectionEntity).

**What I'm try to do is** fetch the sections and related subsections which will be covered be a selected Exam, and store them in a dictionary which can hold multiple string values per key.

**My code starts like this:**

```
var sectionsDictionary = [String:[String]]()

    //---Fetch Section Entity
    let sectionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(exam = %@)", selectedExam)

    let sectionsFetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = SectionEntity.MR_requestAllWithPredicate(sectionPredicate)

    let fetchedSections:NSArray = SectionEntity.MR_executeFetchRequest(sectionsFetchRequest)
```

All good here. But then I try and fetch the subsections related to the selected sections and things go wrong.

**following Code:**

```
  for section in fetchedSections {
        let sectionName = section.valueForKey("name") as! String

        // //error occurs on the line below
        let subsectionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(section = %@)", section as! SectionEntity)

        let subsectionsFetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = SubsectionEntity.MR_requestAllWithPredicate(subsectionPredicate)


        let fetchedSubsections:NSArray = SubsectionEntity.MR_executeFetchRequest(subsectionsFetchRequest)
```

The error I get is:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_SectionEntity_' (0x7fb363e18580) to 'MyApp.SectionEntity' (0x10c9213e0).
```

The next few lines are supposed to iterate through the fetched results, adding their names as values to the dictionary with section names as keys.

```
          for subsection in fetchedSubsections{
            let subsectionName = subsection.valueForKey("name") as! String
            sectionsDictionary[sectionName] = [subsectionName]
        }

    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the class of your `SectionEntitiy` in the core data model editor to `SectionEntity`? Or is it still the default, `NSManagedObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not defining the type of the class for your record

Go to the *Project.xcdatamodeld* file, and select your `SectionEntity`

Check if the field Class is like this

[image]

If it is then write in the Class field "SectionEntity" and press Enter, it should be like this

[image]

Then try again

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the elements of the collection you enumerate are of the correct type.

Presumably, Magical Record will return an `NSArray` of `NSManagedObject` items. You need to make sure Swift knows what type `section` is.

```
for object in fetchedSections {
   let section = object as! SectionEntity
   // ...
}
```

Also, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614152/427083) about the unsuccessful casts to `NSManagedObject` subclasses.