# Cannot access an NSManagedObject subclass's properties (gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am a noob in Core Data with Swift.  I have a single `NSManagedObject` class which looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Polls: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var pollDescription: String

}
```

In a UITableViewController subclass, I have a method for fetching these objects, like this:

```
func refreshPolls()
{
    //do the query to populate the array
    let req = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Polls")
    self.polls = self.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(req, error: nil) as! [Polls]
    println(polls.count)
}
```

Note that `self.polls` is defined as an array of "Polls" objects.

Now, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I am simply doing this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell
    if indexPath.row==0
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EditPollCell") as! UITableViewCell
    }
    else
    {

        let poll:Polls = self.polls[indexPath.row-1] as Polls
        //println(poll.title) //fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

        cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PollCell") as! UITableViewCell
        //cell.textLabel?.text = (poll.valueForKey("title") as! String)


    }

    return cell
```

That commented `println` fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. No additional error info is given, and adding "dynamic" to the `Polls` class's attributes makes no difference.

Why can't I access the `Polls` object's properties? Using the `valueForKey` method fails with the message *"Unexpectedly found a nil value when unwrapping an optional"*, even though the `title` property has a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that your `Polls` array is `NSManagedObject` array.
To check this, try to replace:

```
//println(poll.title) //fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

with

```
println(poll.valueForKey("title"))
```

If this helps, you can check this answer

[CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named)

Comment: I renamed my Entity as a singular (Poll instead of Polls), as suggested in the first answer of the question you linked, and the problem disappeared. I have no idea why. Can you perhaps offer some insight into this? I do not, and did not have, the @objc() annotation in my class. Why does changing the name fix the problem?

Comment: @tutiplain Did you also change class name from `Current Product Module.Polls` to simple `Poll`?

Comment: I am now having the same problem on another view controller. The class name is PollMaster.Poll.  PollMaster is the app name.  This has not changed. The second view controller I am having problems with now says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, accessing the same property.

Comment: Hum, can you share code how you get `Poll` objects in second view controller?

Comment: Hi, after carefully debugging my code I found that the issue with the second view controller had to do with me sending a nil value, and not related to the fact that a Core Data object was being sent. I was finally able to send to another view controller like this: `
                var PollDet:PollDetailsViewController=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PollDetailsViewController") as! PollDetailsViewController
        PollDet.setPoll(self.polls[indexPath.row-1])
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(PollDet, animated: true)`