# Casting NSManagedObject property from num to Bool in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I know that question has been asked many times, but the solutions didn't work with me. I have the following `NSManaged` object class:

```
@NSManaged var cellColor: AnyObject
@NSManaged var des: String
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var switcher: NSNumber
```

And when trying to assign this value to a var as a bool when loading the managed object, I get an error. This is an example of assigning the value to a var:

```
func loadData(){
var appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var context = appDel.managedObjectContext!
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Row")
var result:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
if result.count > 0 {
    for i in result{

        var name = i.name as String
        var des = i.des as String
        var color = i.cellColor as UIColor
        var switcher:Bool{
            get{

            return i.switcher == NSNumber(bool: true) 
            //the problem    happens here
```

However, when I try a simple example of casting in this way, It works well.

How to solve that ??

Comment: I used the integer value (0 and 1) for this case. And the comparison code: i.switcher.integerValue == 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it just like this:

```
for i in results {
    var name = i.name as String
    var des = i.des as String
    var color = i.cellColor as UIColor
    var switcher: Bool {
        return Bool(i.switcher)
    }
}
```

Didn't test that though.

Comment: that:
2015-09-23 03:02:22.327 toDoList[6598:301401] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Row' for entity 'Row'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Ok, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named

Comment: That is not exactly my case