# NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName cannot be typecast to NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a simple entity in my core data stack (called Diary). This entity has one attribute (name)

I generated the NSManagedObject subclass using the Editor. I also made sure that the class name follows **appName**.**DiaryEntry** format

xcode 7 removes the "." and gives me a class with the name: **appNameDiaryEntry**

Here's the code i am using

```
let diaryEntry : DiaryDiaryEntry

diaryEntry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DiaryDiaryEntry", inManagedObjectContext: dataStoreController.managedObjectContext!) as DiaryDiaryEntry
```

In the code above, **DiaryDiaryEntry** is the NSManagedObject subclass that was created from the coredata model.

I get an error saying that

> 'NSManagedObject' is not convertible to 'DiaryDiaryEntry'

If i force a downcast using **as!**, it works but i get an error during run time (because the value was nil and was force unpacking?)

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks, Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have to downcast with `as!` however there's something else that is obviously going wrong when `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(...)` is returning `nil`. You should check if your entity name is correct (has to be the same name as the one specified for the entity in the data model). You might want to have a look at the data model inspector when opening the data model and selecting the desired entity: you have to specify the name of your class under `Class` and select `Current Project Module` under `Module`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Oliver & Marcus. Seems like my managedObject Context is nil for some reason. Please see my comment above...any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I recommend using the **same** entity name and class name. (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614152/427083).) Thus, you should eliminate the (clumsy) "DiaryDiaryEntry", and replace it with "DiaryEntry".

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the class name to match the entity name (previously it wasn't working as xcode was complaining it couldn't find the class but i think i didn't explicitly specify the class name while creating the NSManaged subclass)... I still get the nil exception and it's because of the managedObject context being nil. The storeURL for the controller (that points to MySql.sqlite) does not show anything with that name (i.e. MySql.sqlite) in that location...?

Answer (score 0):

First, since `insert..` returns `AnyObject`, you need to cast it.  There are several ways to do it with `as!` having the highest risk of a runtime crash.

You could also set it up as a guard with something like:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DiaryDiaryEntry", inManagedObjectContext: dataStoreController.managedObjectContext!) as? DiaryDiaryEntry else { fatalError("Failed to load subclass") }
```

Which will still give you a runtime error the way I wrote it but it allows you to control the event.

As for getting a `nil` back, that indicates you have a type in the entity name either in your model or in that line of code.  That line of code should **never** return `nil`.  I suspect your actual entity name is `DiaryEntry`.

As Mundi pointed out, your class name is a bit repetitive.  While he likes to keep the class and model name the same, I prefer to suffix my class names which would make yours `DiaryEntryMO` which I find to be very easy to consume when maintaining code.