# NSArray mismatch Swift Array element type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to display items in the UIPickerView from CoreData. But I always get a `NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type` inside pickerviews titleforrow function. Here's my complete code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Create_New: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{
    var picker = UIPickerView()
    var picker2 = UIPickerView()
    var territory: [String] = []
    var company: [Company] = []
    var facility: [String] = []
    var specialty: [String] = []
    var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        picker2.delegate = self
        picker2.dataSource = self

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Company")
        let fetchRequestTerritory = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Territory")
        let fetchRequestFacility = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Facility")
        let fetchRequestSpecialty = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Specialty")
        let error:NSError

        do {
            let company_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

            company = company_temp as! [Company]
            a = company_temp.count
            print(company.count)

            let territory_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestTerritory)
            territory = territory_temp.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
            b = territory_temp.count
            print(territory_temp.count)

            let facility_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestFacility)
            facility = facility_temp.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
            c = facility_temp.count
            print(facility_temp.count)

            let specialty_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestSpecialty)
            specialty = specialty_temp.flatMap{ $0 as? String }
            d = specialty.count
            print(specialty_temp.count)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


         }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var x = 1
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            //print(territory.count)
            return b
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 2){
            //print(company.count)
            return a
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 3){
            //print(facility.count)
            return c
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 4){
            //print(specialty.count)
            return d
        }
        return x
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        var temp: [String] = []
                if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return  company[a-1].name! as String
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 2){
            return company[a-1].name
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 3){
            return company[a-1].name
        }else if (pickerView.tag == 4){
            return  company[a-1].name
        }
        return temp[row]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do back then is to fetch some records from Coredata and put them in an Array just like what you see in my variable declarations. But I receive an error `AnyObject cannot be converted to String`.
Sorry for this simple question. I am just new in Swift and iOS dev.

**EDIT:**
I get the error from this line: `return  company[a-1].name! as String`

Here's my Company class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


class Company: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
```

xcmodeld:

[image]

I just noticed this text from the output window:
Unable to load class named 'Company' for entity 'Company'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Comment: change company[a-1].name! as String to company[a-1].name as! String

Comment: I get error: `Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?`

Comment: ok, then put ! at the end of the line, like company[a-1].name as String!

Comment: or just return company[a-1].name!

Comment: Can you show us the class `Company`?

Comment: @ogres same problem.

Comment: @Eendje see updated code

Comment: It's just an empty subclass of `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: @Eendje yes. no other content

Comment: @JaysonTamayo Explain what gives Company a `.name` property, please.

Comment: I can't even print its value since i always get the error.

Comment: I think @matt meant, how can your object `Company` have `.name` which is what I'm wondering as well.

Comment: The `name` property might be an attribute defined in`Company+CoreDataProperties.swift`.

Comment: Please see the image i attached @Eendje

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614152/3985749) regarding the "unable to load class named..." error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set the `Module` of the class `Company` in the data model file to `Current Product Module`

The property `name` in `Company` seems to be declared as optional `String`, and since the method returns also an optional `String`, it's probably simply

```
return company[a-1].name
```

Answer (score 1):

`as` casts can only be used for casts guaranteed to succeed (since Swift 1.2 I think). If you really want to force a cast because you know it will be valid you can use `as!` but I always use `as?` in these situations and then handle the optional returned.

You could change:

```
 return company[a-1].name! as String
```

to:

```
return company[a-1].name as? String
```

because the method returns an optional anyway. If it didn't you could handle the nil case with nil-coalescing:

```
return company[a-1].name as? String ?? "-"
```

Where "-" is a suitable fallback.

Comment: I get an error: `Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?` I might be using Swift 2 already

Comment: I thought it was an AnyObject based on the previous error. (You will be on Swift 2. I was only noting in case it came up from an old tutorial.)

Comment: I think vadian's answer is more on target. I think the note about being unable to load the class was the key piece of information.